# Hyperlink within GridViewColumn.CellTemplate issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

How I can adjust WPF Hyperlink within GridViewColumn.CellTemplate?

[image]

---

Special ***thanks*** to **@H.B.** !!

Here is the solution

```
<GridViewColumn   Width="Auto" Header="URL" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>                                   
            <TextBlock  Name="urlToContent" MinWidth="100" Width="Auto">
                <Hyperlink NavigateUri="{Binding Path=URL}" Name="hlkURL"   RequestNavigate="OpenPageRequestNavigate">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=URL}"/>  
                </Hyperlink>
             </TextBlock>
         </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate> </GridViewColumn
```

Comment: Uhm, you should still use a `Run` instead of a `TextBlock` inside the `Hyperlink`...

Comment: @H.B. ahh! I see. Can you explan please why it is better? I guess Run is not so heavy, correct?

Comment: Yes, using a `TextBlock` will also automatially create an `InlineUIContainer` because the contents of Hyperlinks are inlines (flow content) and not UI-Elements, `TextBlocks` and other controls things are "not meant to be there".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextBoxes` do not support [flow content](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753113.aspx), use a `TextBlock`.

Answer (score 0):

As @H.B. says you have to use a TextBlock.

However, you can use a RichTextBox